# Create workflow to notify members a task is complete

Tags: workflow, task-list, workflow-tasks-list, ms-flow

I'm newer to SharePoint and am wondering if there was a way to add a workflow onto a task list (originally opened with project then synced). Basically I want assigned team members to know when the task ahead of theirs is marked completed so that they can begin the next project. Also be notified when documents are uploaded to their task.

We run a website design firm, so I want the Creative Dir to be notified when a graphic designer finishes their "Initial concepts" task and that his task of "review concepts" is ready for him to approve or complete. Then the next task is triggered when he marks his task complete, so forth.

If theres a way to send approvals automatically to outside clients when we've uploaded final concepts so they can approve without having to come in

Can a standard workflow template work for this or would MS flows be better? How do I set these onto the existing task lists.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Kim Robinson, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution :)

Comment: What's your SharePoint Edition? by the way, MS flows is a cloud service that is not worked with on-prem for more details check https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/did-you-consider-powerapps-is-a-replacement-for-sharepoint-designer-and-infopath-in-sharepoint/

Comment: My company has office 365, but I have also installed the suite apps provided.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes a SP designer WF can be attached to Tasks list. Don't use Flow right now there are many changes going in there.
2. You can send notification of task completion using "send email" action in WF once your task is updated/marked as "complete"
3. Approval WF are available with SharePoint. To get it approved form your client, you can add them as external users and provide them with "approve" permission.

Comment: Is there a way using the "send email" action under designer to choose the lookup to contain 'successor' and email the person who is assigned. Trying to automate it so the team doesn't have to notify the next person working on a project that their part is complete. Thanks for you help. I was able to get the basics of what we want set up, now just trying to make it easier.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot use a lookup of 'Person or Group' type column in WF. But if by some means you can store only the E-mail address of successor, you may be able to fulfill your requirements